# NFS slower than SMB between Linux machines

Tags: linux, debian, samba, nfs

I have a QNAP TS-419P II in which I installed Debian Bookworm. I have some NFS and Samba shares to be used by some Windows and Linux clients. I was doing some testing and noticed something weird. I'm getting better speeds on CIFS than NFS even between Linux machines.

Both shares were set up using Webmin, and nothing was changed from the default settings. They are just two shares of the same folder.

With the same source, same target, and same content, I get this:

[image: Transfer Results]

Is this supposed to happen? I suppose not, but how could I troubleshoot what's causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: There may be caching going on. Do you get the same results if you reverse the tests?

Comment: @tink, thank you for the answer.
Do you mean, copy files from the NAS to the PC?
I will try that and post asap.

Comment: @tink, you might be right. I did the same test, of copying the files to the share and then copying it back to the server. 
This is what I got:


`NFS Read: 264 Mb/s; Write: 48 Mb/s | CIFS Read: 232 Mb/s; Write:72 Mb/s`

Can this be related to sync/async? I'm not aware of any other type of caching regarding NFS.

Comment: I'm talking about Linux' (which your NAS is most likely running as well) capability to cache files in RAM, independent of the underlying filesystem. How did you come by the initial figures, btw, what test method were you using?

Comment: My NAS is running vanilla Debian Bookworm and has just Webmin installed to manage it. 
On my server, I mounted both shares (CIFS and NFS4) in different folders, then I use rsync to copy the content of a folder in the server to both shares sequentially. In the end, I'm doing rsync again from the NAS to the server yet again sequentially.
I just noticed using rsync directly from the server to the NAS is even slower.
Using CrystalDiskMark on a Windows machine, I can get much faster results.

Comment: Regarding the first figures, I made a shell script to run the test, and I'm doing the calculations using timestamps at the beginning and at the end of each test to calculate the speed, knowing the size of the content.
What you see are just 'echoes'.